# Variable declaration and assignment syntax with old and new variables

Tags: go

In the beow code:

```
func sumDigitsIter(n int) int {
    digit_sum := 0
    for n > 0 {
        n, last := split(n)
        digit_sum += last
    }
    return digit_sum
}

func split(n int) (int, int) {
    return n / 10, n % 10
}
```

---

`n` cannot be a new `n` in syntax `n, last := split(n)`

Without explicit declaration of `last` variable, How to create a new variable `last` & re-assign value to existing variable `n`, what is the syntax?

Because in python, we do this:

```
def sumDigitsIter(n):
    digit_sum = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, last = split(n)
        digit_sum = digit_sum + last
    return digit_sum
```

Comment: `var last int; n, last = split(n)`. Please see the language spec or even the Tour of Go for trivial language constructs.

Comment: @Volker Query is mis-read. It is my bad.

Answer (score 4):

Declare a new variable using a [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations). Do not use a short variable declaration.

```
func sumDigitsIter(n int) int {
    digit_sum := 0
    for n >= 0 {
        var last int
        n, last = split(n)
        digit_sum += last
    }
    return digit_sum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `n` and `last` are defined in a new block, so `n,last:=v1,v2` will declare `n` and `last` as new variables. If you want to keep `n` and declare `last`, you have to declare it separately:

```
var last int
n,last=split(n)
```

Comment: Yes,  but in python, we don't do this

Comment: This isn't python. Check the language spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations